# Retrieving Spanish Characters from database in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, oc4j

There are few names in database with spanish characters in it. When I query database from java I see '?' instead of those accented characters. I tried passing `'-Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es'` to jvm  but it didn't work as well.

I'm using embeded OC4J in JDevloper 10.1.3.2.0. Do I need configure some settings of JDeveloper/OC4J to retrieve the correct charcters? Please note that this is not the display problem in jsp but the retrieval problem in java.

Thanks,
AndyT

Comment: You should show your code and send more data about DB you are using etc. The environment properties you are using do not make any sense: this is the first time I see property `user.country` (unless this is your application level property).

Comment: @AlexR Code is just a basic database connection and querying database from java using jdbc. Database I'm using is Oracle. Database is on UNIX server while OC4J is on Windows machine. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: How do you "see" the output? Command-line window? Browser? Text file in an editor?  What you see will depend on the method being used to display the data, and not all methods can handle characters outside the standard ASCII character set.

Comment: @Jim Sorry I should have mentioned that I see '?' when I debug the code in JDeveloper. That's why I said it is not a display problem but the retrieval problem. (and I again see '?' in the broswer, which is expected as java is passing '?' to jsp)

Comment: Please somebody help me out here.